# What does a series of dots (elipses) mean after a sentence?

Tags: meaning, terminology

For example you send an email to a acquaintance or friend. "I've been busy. Recovering from unexpected surgery. My recovery is going well. I will send information on that hobby to you soon. Hope you're day is wonderful."

Their response. No problems. Thanks for the note. Hope surgery went well....  Rest up...

What do the dots signify or mean?

Thank you for your input! :)

Comment: The symbol made up of three periods is collectively known as an _elipsis_.

Comment: Thank you. Extra words are not necessary because the simple words used convey the meaning.

Comment: Knowing the name would help you look up the usages, though.

Comment: @keshlam Knowing the name of?

Comment: @seabird The punctuation mark you are speaking about. The *ellipsis*…

Answer (score 4):

Generally they mean some missing part of the text. Here informally they just mean a series of messages with pauses.

Comment: Thank you for your input. So is it the act of leaving out extra words that are not necessary for a phrase to be understood? In other words the simple words he used bring across the meaning? And with the above response using dots it's not conveying rudeness?

Comment: @seabird Yes, that's exactly it. There's no rudeness intended. In a way it could even imply a close relationship between sender and recipient, as the sender must feel that they know each other well enough that any associated extra meanings will be understood without having to spell them out. Or the writer might just be a bit lazy...

Comment: Thank you toandfro. The writer is likely busy right now so he could be a bit lazy. But that doesn't bother me. We all become that way time to time. Or as you mentioned closeness.I'm glad it doesn't mean rudeness.

Comment: I'd just add that correct usage is 3 full stops (dots / periods).